# Let $F$ be Lipschitz. Let $x$ be a solution to $x'=F(x)$. If $\exists t x(t+T) = x(t)$, then $x$ is periodic.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\bf Question$

> Let $F$ be Lipschitz. Let $x$ be a solution to $x'=F(x)$.
>
> If $\exists t\space x(t+T) = x(t)$, then $x$ is periodic with period $T$.

I'm kind of lost with this problem, and I'd like to get some hints (just hints, not a complete answer!).

Could someone show me where to start?

Comment: What do you know for Lipschitz continuous rhs? Did you get known Picard-Lindelöf?

Comment: @Thomas That's uniqueness and existence, right? If so, yes!

Comment: Yes. Existence is already known, so what have you left?

Comment: (additional hint: You will need the fact that $F$ does not depend on $t$)

Comment: I'm sorry, I know I have to use uniqueness somehow, but I couldn't get further. Could you provide another hint?

Comment: $s\mapsto x(s+T)$ and $s\mapsto x(s)$ solve the same initial value problem (for $s=t$), the solution of which is unique.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to do that before, but I couldn't prove that $x_2(s)=x(s+T)$ was a solution to the original equation as well as $x(s)$. If I can get that, then the problem would be solved, right?

Comment: Yes. Note that when $F$ is independent of $t$ then a translated solutions is still a solution. (For any real $a$ the function $t\mapsto x(t+a)$ satisfies $x^\prime(\cdot + a) = F(x(\cdot + a))$) So your $x_2$ solves the original equation, just with different initial values. Now if you know for one $t$ that the initial values coincide, you get the same solution with a parameter shift....